# Heroku cannot GET / due to 'failed to load resource: server responded with status of 404' using node.js

Tags: node.js, npm, heroku, server

Works locally on node server.js

[Image of folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s8tWD.png)

server.js code:

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const db = require('./db/db.json'); //*db = database
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3001;
const app = express();

app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.use(express.static('public'));

app.get('/*/', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname), './public/index.html')
})

//TEXT EDIT: this is at the bottom of the server.js
app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Port is live http://localhost:3001`)
})
```

package.json:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.18.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node Develop/server.js"
  }
}
```

Have spent close to 4 hours on stack overflow trying all the solutions proposed on similar questions.

[heroku logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u5Vs3.png)

Comment: Please include your logs directly and clarify your post into a specific question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
app.get('/*/', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname), './public/index.html')
})
```

changed to:

```
app.get('/*/', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, './public/index.html')
})
```

now getting a different error but at least it's something new

### Resolved the other error so hopefully someone that has been having the same issue as me can see this. The below code

```
app.use(express.static('public'));
```

For some reason, does not work with heroku, but does whenever launching the server with node.js locally. I think this is because I have my server.js file inside the 'develop' folder? Not too sure, but I ended up changing that code to

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

which works